# In my custom kernel, for my IDE disk-read operations I have to multiply the LBA by 2

Tags: c, kernel, qemu, disk, osdev

For my disk-read function,
`int ide_read_sectors(uint8 drive, uint8 num_sectors, uint32 lba, uint32 buffer)`
, the function works as it should for certain small LBA numbers, and then after a while, for example in my inode read function I am forced to do something like

```
ide_read_sectors(DRIVE, 2, 2*(inode_table_start + containing_block), inode_tmp);
```

to get it to work.
This usually gets it working, however upon getting into larger disks, `ide_read_sectors` will throw an error in which the LBA is higher than the total number of disk sectors. Also, I am emulating this kernel in qemu, which may be the problem, so I have attached my qemu args: `

```
qemu-system-i386 -cdrom out/SimpleOS.iso -drive file=ext2.img,format=raw
```

.

I have tried to use this "workaround", and it works fine until a certain LBA number which I can't determine. What actually happened was the function threw an error, because I was asking it to read an LBA that was higher than the disk's actual capacity.

Comment: Are you doing LBA reads using the BIOS or directly interfacing with the controller?

Comment: I am directly interfacing using the controller, as we are in 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: To me it sounds as you have to find the actual error that makes you believe you _have to multiply the LBA by 2_ rather than just circumventing effects in an odd way.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean @Armali

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time finding a way to express what I mean other than how I already did.

Comment: I believe I understand your comment, and I am wondering if this is an error with qemu.